# mysqli + ckeditor = escapes and breaking html

Tags: mysql, ckeditor

So I have been developing a little system in which, at a point, the user can type in some HTML into ckeditor, that HTML is then stored in a database (it's kind of a microCMS).

The problem is When using Mysqli, It inserts escape characters before and after " and ' in order to stop injection, logically, which breaks loads of HTML code.

for example

becomes

or somthing close to that, which breaks the code

Is there a way i can disable the injection prevention, or input it into the database another way ? Or mabi replace the /" when it is being taken from the database ?

Thanks

-jman6495

EDIT :
I have resolved the problem
I replaced the /" by " using the php str_replace function.

here's the code : 
                $pagecontent = str_replace('\"','"',$pagecontent);
                echo $pagecontent;

thanks anyway

-jman6495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing these characters when you fetch data back out you're somehow double-escaping the content. Check that you're only escaping it once, and doing it with the placeholder and not `mysql_real_escape_string`. You haven't fixed the problem. You've un-done the damage of a serious bug.

The purpose of SQL escaping is to insert the data correctly and reliably. For instance, `O'Reilly` should be `O''Reilly` for MySQL. The actual content in the database *should* be `O'Reilly` regardless of quoting.

Comment: Thankyou very much ! (sorry for the very late reply ! )